# What's going on with layout rendering on the Galaxy Nexus?

Tags: android

A very simple project. Here's the Activity subclass:

```
public class Home extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Here's the main.xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Hello World"
    android:textSize="100sp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'd expect this to render as some (very large) text on a plan background, but what actually renders on the Galaxy Nexux (Android 4.0.2) is shown in the screenshot. It renders fine on the other devices I tested.

Am I doing something strange, or is this a bug in the GN Android version?

[image: Screenshot from Galaxy Nexus showing odd rendering of layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your Manifest file:

```
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Comment: Nope, that's not the problem but you were in the right area. I'd forgotten to include the uses-sdk tag. Adding that sorted it out.

Comment: Also android:anyDensity on supports-screens should be true (which is default). According to doco it should be left in most cases, not sure why it got set to false for me!